# ProgressBar animation gets stuck on screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar that uses ObjectAnimator to animate progress, but upon screen rotation, progress gets stuck on the spot right before the activity was destroyed.

Here's the progress drawable:

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="27dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="4dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#DDD" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="27dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#00bdff"
                android:startColor="#00bdff"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Progressbar in XML layout:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hint_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_hint"/>
```

Progressbar in code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ProgressBar hintProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.hint_progress_bar);
    hintProgressBar.setProgress(100);
    animateProgress(hintProgressBar);
}

private void animateProgress(ProgressBar progressBar) {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
```

The animation get's stuck as so:

[image]

I would like to reset progress back to 100 but everything I've tried, setProgress(100) or invalidating doesn't seem to work. Why can't I reset ProgressBar back to 100 on screen rotation?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
```

Comment: I tried it but it's still getting stuck.